# create an empty array with 0 row and 4096 columns this number from feature

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I'm still a beginner with ML, here im reading the images from local folder that contains breast cancer images then compute features for each image with converting the image pixels to a numpy array and prepare the image for the VGG model.

here im creating an empty array with 0 row and 4096 columns this number from fature.

i just need it to be 2048 instead of 4096

```
list_features1 = np.empty((0,4096), float)
```

when i change the number to 2048 it returns :

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 2048 and the array at index 1 has size 4096
```

code :

```
def read_images(folder_path, classlbl):
       # load all images into a list
        images = []
        # dimensions of images
        img_width, img_height = 224, 224
        class1=[]
        for img in os.listdir(folder_path):
            img = os.path.join(folder_path, img)
            img = load_img(img, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
            class1.append(classlbl)# class one.
        #    img = image.img_to_array(img)
        #    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            images.append(img)
        return images, class1  
    #compute features for each image. 
def computefeatures(model,image):
   # convert the image pixels to a numpy array
    image = img_to_array(image)
    # reshape data for the model
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
    # prepare the image for the VGG model
    image = preprocess_input(image)

    # get extracted features
    features = model.predict(image)
    return features
# load model
model = VGG16()
# remove the output layer
model.layers.pop()
model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.layers[-1].output)

# call the image read and 
folder_path = 'C:path'

classlbl=5

images, class1 =read_images(folder_path, classlbl)
# call the fucntion to compute the features for each image. 
list_features1=[]
list_features1 = np.empty((0,4096), float)# create an empty array with 0 row and 4096 columns this number from fature
# extraction from vg16 
for img in range(len(images)):
    f2=computefeatures(model,images[img])
    #list_features1=np.append(list_features1, f2, axis=1)
    list_features1 = np.append(list_features1, f2, axis=0)

classes1 = []
count = 0
for i in range(156):
    if count >= 0 and count <= 156:
        classes1.append(5)
    count = count + 1
print(len(classes1))

df1= pd.DataFrame(list_features1,columns=list(range(1,4097)))
df1['class'] = classes1
dfs = {'40X':df1,} 
# list_features1 :row , 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('multi-classLCResNet.xlsx')
for sheet_name in dfs.keys():
    dfs[sheet_name].to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet_name,index=False)
writer.save()
```

current output :

```
1       2       3       4       4096
0.12    0.23    0.345   0.5372  0.21111
0.2313  0.321   0.214   0.3542  0.46756
.
.
```

desired output :

```
1       2       3       4       2048
0.12    0.23    0.345   0.5372  0.21111
0.2313  0.321   0.214   0.3542  0.46756
.
.
```

Comment: **Do not use** `np.append`.  Stick with the list append that you use elsewhere.  Repeated `np.append` is less efficient.

Comment: @hpaulj, i will but can you please show me how can solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Function `np.empty` is used to create a tensor with **uninitialized** elements rather than tensor with no elements

Comment: What issue you talking about?  I don't see where the 4096 comes from (nor its half). 
 `np.empty((0,2048), float)`.  If you stick with the `list_features1=[]` you first defined, you don't need to create this (0,n) array.

Comment: @tstanisl if i set it to `np.empty((0,2048), float)` it will return error : ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 2048 and the array at index 1 has size 4096

Comment: @hpaulj i will update my question with error that returns if set the number to2048 and with sample

Comment: @jdbcspring, a hpauli said, just stick to `list_features1=[]`. After collecting all `f2` arrays, join `list_features1` using `np.concatenate`. Using `np.append` will likely 1st kill the performance, 2nd you must know the shape in advance.

Comment: @tstanisl can you show me please in the answer section

Comment: It's hard to help you when you don't seem know what you need.

Comment: @hpaulj sorry next time i will be more precise , but it would be really nice and great for future if you teach me what should I replace instead of `list_features1 = np.append(list_features1, f2, axis=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must somehow change the size of `f2` form 4096 to 2048.
Depending on you application, you can skip every 2nd element:

Change:

```
list_features1 = np.empty((0,4096), float)
for img in range(len(images)):
    f2=computefeatures(model,images[img])
    list_features1 = np.append(list_features1, f2, axis=0)
```

to

```
list_features1 = np.empty((0,2048), float)
for img in range(len(images)):
    f2=computefeatures(model,images[img])
    f2 = f2[...,::2] # skip every 2-nd element along the last dimension
    list_features1 = np.append(list_features1, f2, axis=0)
```

Using `np.append` is a very non-optimal solution but it is a separate problem.